# Keycloak OpenID Connect redirect_uri behaves inconsistently

Tags: openid, oauth2, keycloak

I have Keycloak `22.0.5` deployed via docker on my local machine. I have a custom OpenID client configured with its access as follows: [image: Keycloak Access Settings page configured with: Root URL - empty, Home URL - http://localhost:8000, Valid redirect URIs - http://localhost:8000/*, Valid post logout redirect Uris - +, Web Origins - empty, Admin URL - empty]
I don't want to use a password grant, I'm using `pkce` (`authorization_code` variation) grant instead (same way as `account-console` does it).

That's the request I'm sending to the server for authentication:

```
GET localhost:2137/realms/SpringKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/auth?
    client_id=login-user
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000
    &state=af08ea5a-9d4d-4850-9491-483809f2c991
    &response_type=code
    &scope=openid
    &code_challenge=Jqd4T8zNX438YOgW-99eFp_7fbMkDb1Tyu0TtU41x3A
    &code_challenge_method=S256
    &grant_type=pkce
```

Now, the thing is this works perfectly fine, but when I try to get the token, using same `redirect_uri`:

```
POST localhost:2137/realms/SpringKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token

code=ed24eb7c-ef7e-4c51-b545-c59e0717f6a1.54c25efe-7721-4d81-9f64-99493ee365b9.a2b82e1f-84c7-464f-a555-dcea26162e5a
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=login-user
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000
&code_verifier=0a844a24ec41aeb96bc016d8d488794802a066378bbfd35bb8adcf55
```

However it claims, that the url now is invalid:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "invalid parameter: redirect_uri"
}
```

And I don't know what could be causing this behavior. I've looked both through config and through the internet, but I can't find any additional setting that could be causing it.

I've also tried changing the grant type in the second request to `pkce` same way as the first one, but it just raises `unsupported_grant_type`